# Wireless network penetration testing with windows subsystem for linux

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

While checking what kind of packages are available to install on the subsystem, I noticed that tools like aircrack-ng, wifite, reaver ... are available. However, ifconfig doesn't work, and iwconfig shows something like:

```
eth0        no wireless extensions.
wifi0       no wireless extensions.
wifi1       no wireless extensions.
lo          no wireless extensions.
und0        no wireless extensions.
und1        no wireless extensions.
```

I understand that this might be because WSL translates each individual syscall to its Windows variant instead of running a full linux system.
So, my question is: in that case, can we do any wireless network penetration testing with the previously mentioned tools? If not, why are those packages available in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The packages are available because WSL installs an *unmodified Ubuntu image*, including the stock Ubuntu package repositories. It is not a custom WSL-tailored distribution.